# How to compare two data while data-binding in nested for loop in knockout

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

Let there be a JSON file containing :

```
{
    "First" : [
           "A",
           "B",
           "C"
     ],
     "Second" : [
            { "name" : "A"},
            { "name" : "C"}
      ]
}
```

Now, below is a small part of my HTML code to show what I am trying to achieve :

```
<span data-bind="foreach: First">
    <span data-bind="foreach: Second">
        //if First.A === Second.name then do something
    </span>
</span>
```

**How do i do that comparison ?** 
I tried many things but couldn't figure out the correct way.
I know **$data** can be used to access the value of **"First"** here but what to use in this nested loop ?
I am new to this. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Just a little more information:
My HTML code is actually something like this :

```
<span data-bind="foreach: first">
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: $root.second">
                    <tr data-bind="if: $parent === $data.name">
                        //do something
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
.
.
.
</span>
```

This doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the html at the end of your question is not valid: you can't have a `tbody` in a `span` (try it: you'll see the browser ignores the `tbody`).

Now, to your question: I coded a view model that resmebles your case, and an according html.

What's important to understand here is that `$parent` refers to the view model object in the parent context . Thus, in the following html, the `$parent` in `foreach: $parent.seconds` refers to `myVM` context, while the `$parent` in the `if: $parent` refers to the `firsts` context.

```js
var myVM = function () {                                     
  var self = this;
  self.firsts = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
  self.seconds = [{ "name" : "A"}, { "name" : "C"},];
};
ko.applyBindings(new myVM());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<span data-bind="foreach: firsts">
  <span data-bind="foreach: $parent.seconds">
    <span data-bind="if: $parent == $data.name">hello!</span>
  </span>
</span>
```

There are other ways to code it, and another one would be - if it's more convenient for you - changing `$parent.seconds` to `$root.seconds` (and get the same result):

```js
var myVM = function () {                                     
  var self = this;
  self.firsts = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
  self.seconds = [{ "name" : "A"}, { "name" : "C"},];
};
ko.applyBindings(new myVM());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<span data-bind="foreach: firsts">
  <span data-bind="foreach: $root.seconds">
    <span data-bind="if: $parent == $data.name">hello!</span>
  </span>
</span>
```

Moreover, we can improve readability by adding aliases:

```js
var myVM = function () {                                     
  var self = this;
  self.firsts = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
  self.seconds = [{ "name" : "A"}, { "name" : "C"},];
};
ko.applyBindings(new myVM());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<span data-bind="foreach: { data: firsts, as: 'first' }">
  <span data-bind="foreach: { data: $root.seconds, as: 'second' }">
    <span data-bind="if: first == second.name">hello!</span>
  </span>
</span>
```

Comment: To keep the `$parent`/`$data` thing a bit easier to read, the `foreach` binding also supports adding an explicit [alias](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note-3-using-as-to-give-an-alias-to-foreach-items).

Comment: Hi @HeyJude, thanks for your help. In your first solution, I am getting this error : ReferenceError: $parent is not defined. And in your second solution, I am not getting any result. Can you please help.

Comment: Hi @HeyJude, I have added a small section of code in my question in the bottom. Please have a look. Thanks

Comment: @MazharMIK, I added a paragraph at the beginning of my question regarding your added html: it's simply not a valid html. You should restructure your html, and then just simply use my suggested solution.